# How to map OneToOne relationship with YAML

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a OneToOne relationship between two tables using YAML. I'm not sure how they are supposed to communicate.

```
class Games
{

    private $id;


    private $title;


    private $description;


    private $img_link;


    private $website_link;


    private $pegi;


    private $release_date;

    private $requirements;
}

App\Entity\Games:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: App\Repository\GamesRepository
  table: games
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    title:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    description:
      type: text
      nullable: true
    img_link:
      type: text
      nullable: true
    website_link:
      type: text
      nullable: true
    pegi:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    release_date:
      type: date
      nullable: true
  OneToOne:
    requirements:
      targetEntity: App\Entity\Requirements
      joinColumn:
        name: requirements_fk
        referencedColumnName: id

class Requirements
{
    private $id;

    private $os_min;

    private $cpu_min;

    private $ram_min;

    private $hdd_min;

    private $gpu_min;

    private $directx_min;

    private $os_req;

    private $cpu_req;

    private $ram_req;

    private $hdd_req;

    private $gpu_req;

    private $directx_req;
}

App\Entity\Requirements:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: App\Repository\RequirementsRepository
  table: requirements
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    os_min:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    cpu_min:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    ram_min:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    hdd_min:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    gpu_min:
      type: string
      lenght: 255
      nullable: true
    directx_min:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    os_req:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    cpu_req:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    ram_req:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    hdd_req:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    gpu_req:
      type: string
      lenght: 255
      nullable: true
    directx_req:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
```

I try querying it like this, but it always returns null even though it should return an entry.

```
$temp = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Games::class)->find($id);
$requirements = $temp->getRequirements();
```

I don't get any errors so, it's really hard to try and debug it. Acording to documentation it looks okay. So, not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Use backquotes for inline code only. For multiline code snippets & YAML select the block and indent it with Ctrl+K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem is that OneToOne != oneToOne in YAML.

Answer (score 0):

If `class Games` is your entity you should have the method `getRequirements()` in there.
Try to generate the entities based on the schema if your entities are empty.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: I do have all the getters and setters auto-generated. Just, didn't want to have a huge block of repetitive code here. Should have mentioned that though. My bad.

Comment: Can you show me the content of `getRequirements()` method ?

Comment: public function getRequirements()
{
    return $this->requirements;}

    public function setRequirements($requirements): void
    {
        $this->requirements = $requirements;
    }